# An error occured SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: parameter was not defined

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

The following code fails with the error
"An error occuredSQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: parameter was not defined".
Please help to solve this.  Thank you

```
$email = $_POST['email'];
           $username = $_POST['username'];
           $password = password_hash($_POST['password'], PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
           $mobileno = $_POST['mobileno'];        
           $organization = $_POST['organization'];
           $orgaddress = $_POST['orgaddress'];
           try
           {
                $sqlInsert = "INSERT INTO users (username, password, email, mobileno, organization, orgaddress, join_date) 
                     VALUES (:username, :password, :email, :mobileno, :organization, :orgaddress, now())";

                $statement = $db->prepare($sqlInsert);
                $statement->execute(array(':username' => $username, ':password' => $password, ':email' => $email, ':mobileno' => $mobileno, 
                     ':organization' => $organization, ' :orgaddress' => $orgaddress));

                if($statement->rowCount() == 1)
                {
                    $result = "<p style='padding:20px; font-size: 15px; color:green;'>Registration Successful </p>"; 
                }
           }
           catch (PDOException $ex)
           {
                $result = "<p style='padding:20px; font-size: 15px; color:red;'>An error occured" . $ex->getMessage() ."</p>";
           }
```

Comment: join_date column  is `date` type or `datetime`?

Comment: Join_date is 'timestamp'

Comment: `$time = time();` and instead of `now()` use `:time` and then in array `':time'=>$time` do like it and check once

Comment: No, it shows the same error message

Answer (score 0):

Instead of putting an associative array in the execute function, you need to call the bindParam or bindValue function like so:

`$statement->bindValue(':key',  $value)`